# How to collapse all groups and show label vertically in inbox Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to achieve this in outlook 2016
[image: Outlook 2016]

Currently when I collapse the menu, it remains blank. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show all folder names there because you can have many of them. In Outlook 2016, when you collapse the folder pane, it shows all connected mailboxes (top part) and navigation modes (bottom part).